# How can I create a json object using Angular and display it using html?

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

Basically I am working with a json object that I know nothing about, I don't know its keys, I don't know its value. I managed get work with it and process all the information that I want, at the end I have an array (I need an array to be able to do what I want) with all the keys and their paths in the json. Is there a way I can put it back in a json and display it using html ?

Comment: What have you tried? We only know as much as you know about the problem

Comment: Well, I am still trying to find answers on the internet and figure out an answer

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a devTool to display your json Object you can do this in your template :

```
<div>{{ yourObject | json}}</div>
```

Comment: or even better wrap it in `<pre></pre>` as the json filter will do newlines and indentation for you.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Simple Javascript: `const arrayAsJson = JSON.stringify(yourArray)`

Step 2: To display the data follow the answer from *@Bougarfaoui El houcine* and as mentioned in the comments to get a formated output:

```
<pre>{{ arrayAsJson | json }}</pre>
```